# discord.js v12 - Warn command for each guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have script for `warn command` and i need help with that, because this
code working, this command saving warns in `warnings.json`, but when i warn someone that warn be in every guild i want only in one guild warns. Please help :D

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const fs = require('fs')
const warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./warnings.json", "utf8"))

const moment = require('moment')

module.exports = {
  name: "warn",
  description: "Wysyła ankiete",
  guildOnly: true,
  cooldown: 5,

  run(msg, args) {

    // Embed na permisjebota
    const permisjebota = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("⛔ Nie mam uprawnień! :O")
    .setColor('ffff00')
    .setDescription("Nie mam uprawnień do tej komendy! Daj mi uprawnienia lub skonsultuj się z adminem serwera")
    .setTimestamp()
    // Embed na permisje dla użytkownika
    const permisje = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Nie masz permisji do tej komendy! :O")
    .setColor('ffff00')
    .setDescription("Nie masz uprawnień do tej komendy! Jeżeli uważasz, że to błąd skonsultuj się z adminem serwera!")

    if (!msg.member.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
        return msg.channel.send(permisjebota)
    if (!msg.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return msg.channel.send(permisje)

    if(!args[0, 1]) {
        const bananekbot = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Nie podałeś argumentów!")
        .setColor('ffff00')
        .setDescription("Poprawne użycie: `m!warn <nick> <powód>`")
        return msg.channel.send(bananekbot)
    }

    var warnUser = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.get(args[0]))

    var reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

    if (!warnUser) return msg.channel.send("Brak argumentu poprawne użycie: m!warn <nick> <powód>")

    if (!warns[warnUser.id]) warns[warnUser.id] = {
        warns: 0,
    } 

    warns[warnUser.id].warns++

    fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (err) =>{
        if(err) console.log(err)
    })

    const warnembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("✅ Nadano warna")
    .setColor('ffff00')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setDescription(`Użytkownik: ${warnUser} (${warnUser.id})
    Nadający warna: ${msg.author}
    Powód: ${reason}`)
    return msg.channel.send(warnembed)
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe check the guild ID or something, and if the guild ID isn't equal to yours, then it does nothing. Not too sure if its possible though (probably is)

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution to this is to have warnings.json as an array, and in side containing an object with guild id, warns and anything else you need to store. So warnings.json ends up something like this.

```
[
    {
        "guild_id": "12345678901234",
        "an_extra": "Thing",
        "warns": [
            "your_warns",
            "are_here",
            "store_in_any_format"
        ]
    },
    {
        "guild_id": "12345678901234",
        "an_extra": "Guild",
        "warns": [
            "so_on",
            "And so forth",
            "go the warns and guilds"
        ]
    }
]
```

This way, you can simply do `Array.find(guild => guild.guild_id === msg.guild.id)` (Assuming the guild you are trying to access is `msg.guild`).

Learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) about Array.prototype.find()